# Where is the Windows App Runtime for V1.1.2 (particularly the DDLM component), please?

Tags: windows-app-sdk

NuGet delivered the `Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK v1.1.2` yesterday (2022-07-02). My updated WinUI 3 programs now produce the following message when run:

```
    This application requires the Windows App Runtime Version 1.1
       (MSIX package version >= 1002.543.1943.0)
```

I uninstalled previous versions of the runtime and ran the suggested installer (from an elevated PowerShell prompt):

```
Installing license: MSIX_MAINPACKAGE_LICENSE
Install result : 0x0
Installing license: MSIX_SINGLETONPACKAGE_LICENSE
Install result : 0x0
Deploying package: Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1000.516.2156.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Package deployment result : 0x0
Deploying package: Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1000.516.2156.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Package deployment result : 0x0
Deploying package: MicrosoftCorporationII.WinAppRuntime.Main.1.1_1000.516.2156.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Package deployment result : 0x0
Provisioning result : 0x0
Deploying package: MicrosoftCorporationII.WinAppRuntime.Singleton_1000.516.2156.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Package deployment result : 0x0
Provisioning result : 0x0
Deploying package: Microsoft.WinAppRuntime.DDLM.1000.516.2156.0-x6_1000.516.2156.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Package deployment result : 0x0
Provisioning result : 0x0
Deploying package: Microsoft.WinAppRuntime.DDLM.1000.516.2156.0-x8_1000.516.2156.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Package deployment result : 0x0
Provisioning result : 0x0
All install operations successful.
```

Although none of the package FullNames included the sought-for version number 1002.543.1943,  this was the result:

```
(get-appxpackage micro*win*appruntime*).packagefullname
Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1002.543.1943.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1002.543.1943.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MicrosoftCorporationII.WinAppRuntime.Main.1.1_1002.543.1943.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.WinAppRuntime.DDLM.1000.516.2156.0-x6_1000.516.2156.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MicrosoftCorporationII.WinAppRuntime.Singleton_1002.543.1943.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.WinAppRuntime.DDLM.1000.516.2156.0-x8_1000.516.2156.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

All of the components are of the required version except for the DDLM components (note that if you do not run the installer as an administrator, you only get the 1002 version of the principal runtime components. The .Main* and .Singleton* will be *_1000.516.2156*).

The problem is, the programs are looking for that DDLM module and they both have an MSIX version number of `1000.516.2156.0` (although they also have a dependency on `Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1002.543.1943.0_x??__8wekyb3d8bbwe`).

Does anyone know where I can get an MSIX for the `1002.543.1943.0_x??` DDLM component of the runtime? Or a runtime installer that contains all of the components with the required version number?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/2682) for this.

Comment: Thanks @EddieLotter. TheAxe is definitely the best for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today (2022-07-05), the download links on the official Microsoft page ([Downloads for the Windows App SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/downloads)) contain all of the correct versions for the latest update (v1.1.2) to the Windows App Runtime.

Just a note: I removed all of my prior installations of the runtime from a PowerShell prompt before running `WindowsAppRuntimeInstall.exe`. Running `(get-appxpackage micro*win*appruntime*).packagefullname` reported no packages but trying to install the new runtime still gave me an error (package already installed but has different contents than the installed version). Although I am the only user of this machine, previous installs added the runtime to system accounts.

To see all installations, run `(get-appxpackage micro*win*appruntime* -AllUsers).packagefullname` from an elevated PowerShell prompt. Look for versions of the runtime with versions of *1002.*, *DDLM.1001*, and *DDLM.1000*. These may be the culprit as they were all in various versions of the runtime installer (v1.1.2) after it first dropped on July 1st. To remove them from all users, run `Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers -PackageName {package full name}`. After removing versions that might have been in the "naughty" packages, try running the new `WindowsAppRuntimeInstall.exe` again. Everything should work.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem again. Followed your PowerShell commands to remove all older packages (I had 3 with different versions) and left the one VS asked to run the app 
(Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1004.584.2120.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe) but I'm still geting the error asking for this very package.

Comment: Incidentally, PowerShell doesn't recognize the -PackageName switch

Comment: Do you have the WinUI 3 Gallery installed? If so, you can't remove a module that is being used by another MSIX-packaged program with these instructions so uninstall the Gallery and try again.

Comment: Try -Package instead of -PackageName, although -PackageName should work. What version of PS are you using? Mine is 5.1.22000.832.

Comment: Hi atunbul, "Do you have the WinUI 3 Gallery installed?" that was exactly the problem. I had that open. Last night I installed the package by dobleclicking  on the downloaded exe. The command window flashed too quickly to read. This morning I ran the install from an elevatend cmd window and saw the error message: "Unable to install because the following apps need to be closed Microsoft.WinUI3ControlsGallery_1.3.15.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.One or more install operations failed." After closing the gallery the package installed. The confusing part is that PS showed it as installed ???

Comment: ... my PS doesn't print its version # on the startup banner,  it is whatever comes with the latest update of Windows. I'm running 20H2 (OS Build 19402.1890). 
Anyway, just using Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers and the package name works just fine.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. The install script seems to think everything is fine if one (or more) of the modules install. The key thing is to use PS in elevated mode. Try the cmdlet "$PSVersionTable.PSVersion" in PS to get the version, etc. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

What I have learned (thanks @aturnbul) is that to ensure a correct framework package update:

- Close the WinUI 3 gallery and any other app using the framework.
- Using the PowerShell commands listed by aturnbul remove all older packages
- Run **WindowsAppRuntimeInstall.exe** from an elevated command prompt, so you can see any error that it may throw.

Back in PS you can verify that the installation was complete.

// After a failed installation you get only a partial list of packages

```
PS C:\Windows\system32>  (get-appxpackage micro*win*appruntime* -AllUsers).packagefullname
Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1004.584.2120.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1004.584.2120.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

// After a successful installation you get all the packages

```
PS C:\Windows\system32>  (get-appxpackage micro*win*appruntime* -AllUsers).packagefullname
Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1004.584.2120.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1004.584.2120.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MicrosoftCorporationII.WinAppRuntime.Main.1.1_1004.584.2120.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
MicrosoftCorporationII.WinAppRuntime.Singleton_1004.584.2120.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.WinAppRuntime.DDLM.1004.584.2120.0-x6_1004.584.2120.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Microsoft.WinAppRuntime.DDLM.1004.584.2120.0-x8_1004.584.2120.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```